# Querydsl - Could not determine data type for searched case statement

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

This question was sort-of answered a couple of years ago (with a similar title), but I am struggling mightily with it.  It seems that no matter what expression I put in the then() predicate, I keep getting a Hibernate error:

Could not determine data type for searched case statement

Basically here is a simplified code segment that is causing the issue:

```
SimpleExpression<String> adjustmentFlag = 
        new CaseBuilder()
                .when(myObject.id.isNotNull())
                .then(Expressions.asString("true"))
                .otherwise(Expressions.asString("false"));
```

When I use it in a simple select statment, the specific error I get is this:

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not determine data type for searched case statement [ select ...stuff...,  (case when (myObject.id is not null) then ?2 else ?3 end) from ....table list... ]

No matter what I put into the then() or otherwise() methods, nothing seems to work.  From other posts, they talk about using Expressions - I've tried all kinds, and come up with the same error each time.

Anyone else having issues like this?  It seems this would be such a common problem, but I'm stumped as to how to proceed next.  Any help would be appreciated.

Using Querydsl 4.1.3, Hibernate 5.0.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - figured it out.  It actually wasn't the expressions in the then() or otherwise() methods - it was the literals I was using in the when() condition.  I changed them to use Expressions. and it is now working.